# Hacking my profile and changing it

Tags: discussion

I noticed a few weeks ago that my StackExchange profile had been hacked, and that my original one line of text had been overridden and replaced with malicious text.

Earlier today I over-wrote that malicious text with an extended 2991-character new profile, but now I've found that that the cockroach (program??) had shit on my brand new profile again, and with the same malicious text.

I had really been looking forward to working with other StackExchange members in the (currently) nine SE websites that I'm registered in, but with a cockroach on the loose happily deleting and replacing my profile with the cockroach's poop, the only alternative I can see is for me to click on the SE icon on my desktop, pull that icon down to that "wastebasket" icon down there in the lower right hand corner of my desktop, and drop the SE icon into it.  Then next, I will delete the SE program entirely from my computer.

I really have liked SE, but I've been personally attacked in the Russian Language forum by a cockroach going by the name of "Artimex", who may or may not be the source behind the malicious attack on my Profile.  But be that as it may, I'm not taking any chances on the cockroach that's running around in your program corrupting the rest of my computer.

Any help before I say "*au revoir*" and "*доствданя*" to  you all, and then delete SE from my computer?

Comment: What are you talking about? We do not have a "program" that runs on your computer and you have never edited your profile on any sites on our network past the initial display name change.

Comment: @animuson: Looks like A51 is customized, but that's the only one.

Comment: Yes, there's a outside chance that someone indeed changed your profile, and there's an even smaller chance it was malicious. But even if [you don't catch more flies with honey than vinegar](https://www.xkcd.com/357/), you certainly make more friends be being nice. Additionally, moderators may [edit profiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208551/274942) if said profile is overly offensive in some way. This is extremely uncommon, but it may have happened. Not knowing the supposed original contents of your profile, I of course cannot guarantee that this is what happened, but it's a possibility.

Comment: "Outside chance"?  C'mon.  I appreciate your "making friends with honey" analogy, but I'm not using this website as a media for social interaction, like Facebook.  I'm using StackExchange to answer questions about subjects that I know a lot about, and also to ask questions about subjects that I don't know much about.  From what I've Googled and read about the originators' concept of what StackExchange should be, they definitely did not include 'making nice' to hackers and trolls in their concept.  The answer I was looking for is in the first answer I received (below).  I'll follow up on it.

Comment: You do know that Artimex does not exist on Russian Language correct?

Comment: You are right, I'm wrong.  Thank you.  The correct name is "Artemix", not "Artimex".  You can view in SE Russian Language my answer, his answer and our mutual comments to the question topic "Аналог словаря Макмилана для изучающих русский язык".  You can note that Artemix  incrementally added negative votes to my answer, starting with -2, then after my comments increasing it to -3, and then again following my comments to -4, where it remains at this moment.

Answer (score 7):

If you think you have been hacked, please use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button in the footer to contact the SE team directly.

Note that they will require you to provide sufficient proof of ownership of the account.

There is nothing else we can do to help you here.